# Django - python manage.py runserver error

Tags: django

after python manage.py runserver using VScode that

$ python manage.py runserver
Python

I don't know why it works like this.
How can I make it work according to the instructions?

[image]

Comment: could you provide more details about what you want to do? and what is the error you are receiving if you are receiving any?

Comment: I downvoted because the question didn't propose the problem with sufficient details. Without an error print-out, context of the project structure, etc., there is no way for us to reliably help you. Please add more information to your question.

Comment: Show the contents of `manage.py`. Also what does the command `which python` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I don't know if I understand well but normally the correct way to run this command is  python manage.py runserver PORT(port in optional) for example:
`python manage.py runserver 8080`
or just
`python manage.py runserver`
And, be sure you are inside your django project folder.

Comment: i did python manage.py runserver 8080. but it didn't work